# Copying a large directory tree crashes my PC

Tags: backup, sync

Windows 7.  I have been happily using [PT replicator](http://www.karenware.com/powertools/ptreplicator.asp), which is a backup program with some good features, but since I got an external 2TB and a 4TB drive, I can't copy a whole directory tree.

The PC reboots overnight with PT Replicator, or with Total Commander; Allway sync & go runs out of memory building the file list, as does Tera Copy.

Please, do not downvote or close this; I am not asking for a "best" solution, just anything that works. I *have* googled & I have tried several programs, I just can't find a solution.

Ideally, I would like something that allows me to add exclusions, e.g. `$RECYCLE.BIN`, `System Volume Information`, `*.bak`, etc I would also like to to mirror file deletions.

But I will take anything that I can get as I desperately need automated backup.

Perhaps another solution would be a directory monitor program, which would backup/replicate deletion in real time?

Or perhaps I should just code my own...

[Update] Sync toy also runs out of memory. I have 8gB plus 8gB swap space.

Btw, I want somethign with a GUI and preferably with a lot of flexibility. It is beginning to look like I will need to code my own & go file by fiel, rather than buidling alist of all files first, which is what seems to be crashing them all. None of them get as far as copying the first file

Comment: Have you tried SyncToy? http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15155

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three programs that come to mind are:

[robocopy](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17657) -- free command line tool from microsoft.

[cwrsync](https://www.itefix.no/i2/cwrsync) -- a windows version of rsync. this is especially an awesome tool if you are copying between two computers that support rsync. alternatively, you can also install the cygwin version.

third that comes to mind is [bvckup](http://www.bvckup.com/) . I've used it for mirroring with great success. The exclusion part of the software is a little confusing, but it works with some patience.

Comment: BvBAckup seems to be the only one with aGUI. It crashes too. I have emailed the crash log to their support team